# SQL - Getting data from joins if other joins are null

Tags: sql, join, group-by, union, distinct

I have been trying many solutions, but haven't quite found one that works right yet. Any help is appreciated. I am using SQL Server.

I have some tables like this:

**CARS**

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
| CarId |    CarImage     |    CarVideo     |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     1 | http://imageurl | http://videourl |
|     2 | http://imageurl | http://videourl |
|     3 | http://imageurl | http://videourl |
|     4 | http://imageurl | http://videourl |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**CAR NAMES**

```
+----+-------+---------+------------+
| Id | CarId | CarName | LanguageId |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
|  1 |     1 | Car 1   |          1 |
|  2 |     1 | Bil 1   |          2 |
|  3 |     2 | Car 2   |          1 |
|  4 |     2 | Bil 2   |          2 |
|  5 |     3 | Car 3   |          1 |
|  6 |     3 | Bil 3   |          2 |
|  7 |     4 | Car 4   |          1 |
|  8 |     4 | Bil 4   |          2 |
+----+-------+---------+------------+
```

**CARS_NICKS**

```
+--------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| NickId | UserId | CarId |      CarImage       |      CarVideo       |
+--------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1 |      1 |     1 |                     |                     |
|      2 |      1 |     2 | http://NEW-imageurl |                     |
|      3 |      1 |     3 |                     | http://NEW-videourl |
|      4 |      2 |     1 |                     | http://NEW-videourl |
+--------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**CARS_NICKS_NAMES**

```
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| Id | NickId |   CarName    | LanguageId |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | Nickname 1   |          1 |
|  2 |      1 | Nicknavn 1   |          2 |
|  3 |      4 | Nickname 1-2 |          1 |
|  4 |      4 | Nicknavn 1-2 |          2 |
|  5 |      2 | Nickname 2   |          1 |
|  6 |      2 | Nicknavn 2   |          2 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

What I want to do is to show a list of cars, like this:

Cars (for UserId 1)

```
+-------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| CarId |  CarName   |      CarImage       |      CarVideo       |
+-------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     1 | Nickname 1 | http://imageurl     | http://videourl     |
|     2 | Nickname 2 | http://NEW-imageurl | http://videourl     |
|     3 | Car 3      | http://imageurl     | http://NEW-videourl |
|     4 | Car 4      | http://imageurl     | http://videourl     |
+-------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Cars (for UserId 2)

```
+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| CarId |   CarName    |      CarImage       |      CarVideo       |
+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     1 | Nickname 1-2 | http://imageurl     | http://NEW-videourl |
|     2 | Nickname 2   | http://NEW-imageurl | http://videourl     |
|     3 | Car 3        | http://imageurl     | http://NEW-videourl |
|     4 | Car 4        | http://imageurl     | http://videourl     |
+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

What this is doing, is basically getting all the default information for each car from the Cars and CarNames table. However, I want this data to be overwritten by the Cars_Nicks and Cars_Nicks_Names tables if it exists.

In our application, each User basically has a "teacher". And the setting for each teacher will also be the default for each of their students, unless the student has themselves set up nicks as well. So in this case, UserId 1 is a "teacher" to UserId 2. So that's why in UserId 2's table, they have some data for UserId 1, but also their own nicks, in addition to the default Cars information if a certain data point does not exist in the nicks.

I have tried different solutions to make this happen with `JOIN`, `UNION`, `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT`, and all combinations I could think with these. But I keep ending up with multiple results such as the following table:

Cars (for UserId 2) (my attempt)

```
+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| CarId |   CarName    |      CarImage       |      CarVideo       |
+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     1 | Nickname 1   | http://imageurl     | http://videourl     |
|     1 | Nickname 1-2 | http://imageurl     | http://NEW-videourl |
|     2 | Nickname 2   | http://NEW-imageurl | http://videourl     |
|     2 | Car 2        | http://imageurl     | http://videourl     |
|     3 | Car 3        | http://imageurl     | http://NEW-videourl |
|     3 | Car 3        | http://imageurl     | http://videourl     |
|     4 | Car 4        | http://imageurl     | http://videourl     |
+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could get this?

This was one of my many attempts:

```
SELECT
    CarId,
    ISNULL(CarNicks.CarName, CarNames.CarNames) CarNames,
    ISNULL(CarNicks.CarImage, Cars.CarImage) CarImage,
    ISNULL(CarNicks.CarVideo, Cars.CarVideo) CarVideo
FROM 
    Cars
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT CarId, CarName, CarImage, CarVideo
     FROM Cars_Nicks Nicks
     JOIN Cars_Nicks_Names NickNames ON NickNames.NickId = Nicks.NickId 
                                     AND NickNames.LanguageId = 1 AND UserId = 1
     UNION
     SELECT CarId, CarName, CarImage, CarVideo
     FROM Cars_Nicks Nicks
     JOIN Cars_Nicks_Names NickNames ON NickNames.NickId = Nicks.NickId  
                                     AND NickNames.LanguageId = 1 AND UserId = 2) CarNicks ON CarNicks.CarId = Cars.CarId
JOIN 
    CarNames ON CarNames.CarId = Cars.CarId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting link, I have updated. Do you have any ideas on the query I could use?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that. PS  A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".

Comment: Thanks philipxy, I have added that I am using MSSQL. Otherwise though, I believe I have given the minimal reproducible example for what my question is, and the data I have

Comment: We can't cut & paste & run--so no [mre]. Also there is not a clear specification, just some "basically"s with vague phrases--no [mre]. Please also see my last comment, which crossed yours. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to bring together the various tables without duplicating the join keys. You should (outer) join all three tables `Cars`, `Cars_Nicks`, and `Cars_Nicks_Names` just once using `CarId` and `NickId` as the respective join keys. This naturally produces multiple records per `CarId`, but (if I understand your data model correctly) should only produce one nickname per `CarId`, `User`, and `Language` at most. You will need to join the nicknames for the teacher as *another copy* of the `Cars_Nicks` and `Cars_Nicks_Names` tables, suitably renamed so you can identify whether the nickname is coming from the student or the teacher.

Use `COALESCE` to make one thing have priority over something else. In the `SELECT` clause you'll do something similar to your originally posted attempt for fields where you want the value from one of the tables to override the value in a field from another table, and the last item in each list should be the ultimate fallback value.

Don't use `UNION` for this case.

The following is an untested example for just the name. It's fairly easy to expand the things being joined to include the other fields you want in your output.

```
select Cars.CarId, Cars.LanguageId, coalesce( StudentNN.CarName, TeacherNN.CarName, Cars.CarName ) as CarName
  from
      Car_Names left join (
           select NickId from Cars_Nicks where UserId = :student
      ) StudentN using (CarId)
      left join (
          select NickId from Cars_Nicks where UserId = :teacher
      ) TeacherN using (CarId)
      left join (
          select CarName from Cars_Nicks_Names
      ) StudentNN on StudentN.NickId = StudentNN.NickId and Car_Names.LanguageId = StudentNN.LanguageId
      left join (
          select CarName from Cars_Nicks_Names
      ) TeacherNN on TeacherN.NickId = TeacherNN.NickId and Car_Names.LanguageId = TeacherNN.LanguageId
```

Comment: Seems maybe union is relevant--a student's own nick supercedes a teacher nick, then we union Cars rows with rows based on those nicks. But the specification is not clear.

Comment: I have tried by simply left joining Car_Nick_Names twice (once for the student id, and once for the teacher id) to the Cars_Nicks table ... but even that is returning multiple rows for each despite using the COALESCE for the CarName

Comment: Which is because some data does have multiple rows because it has both teacher and student data

Comment: yeah, this should work now. Unfortunately having to do an extra set of 2 left joins for that, but I think that it is probably the best solution to this point. thanks

Comment: as long as you can use a sentinel ID for the users that have no teachers, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to `inner join` tables `cars`, `cars_nicks` and `car_names`, and then bring in `car_nick_names` with a `left join`. Then you can implement the substitution logic with `coalesce()`:

```
select
    ni.userid,
    ni.carid,
    coalesce(nn.carname, na.carname) carname
    coalesce(ni.carimage, ca.carimage) carimage,
    coalesce(ni.carvideo, ca.carvideo) carvideo
from cars ca
inner join cars_nicks ni on ni.carid = ca.carid
inner join car_names na on na.carid = ca.carid and na.languageid = 1
left join cars_nicks_names nn on nn.nickid = ni.nickid and nn.language_id = 1
```

You gave no explanation on how to manage the `languageid` column, that is present in the `*_names` tables so I forced it to a fixed value. In the real world, you would have a `users` table that stores the user language, and use that value for filtering.

Comment: That is true, for the LanguageId. I have a users table to get that, but setting it equal to 1 as you did was fine for the basic idea. Sorry about that. As for the query, this is showing me that maybe I need to do 4 left joins from the main cars table. I need to LEFT JOIN for each of cars_nicks ON UserId = 1, cars_nicks_names on that table's NickId, and then also repeat the same thing but for cars_nicks ON UserId = 2, etc

Comment: see the example I posted in my answer